# Update User Auto Renewal Subscription from backend

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

So our ios app has issue of not updating the expiry date. 
Now we want to update all users expiry date from directly our php backend using the verify apple receipt code of node js

But the problem is data base has no purchase id, installion id.. so how do we identify and get the receipt of X user

we are looking at https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-apple-receipt-verify

So User1 emails us he purchased the auto renewal but it did not renew, now we want to update User1's expiry date before he opens the app

Answer (score 1):

You have the send the receipt from the iOS app to your server. Ideally you should do this when the user makes a purchase, but it can be done at anytime. You should store this on the backend with that users info. This is the receipt you need to send when making the validate and verify calls to apple.

I haven't used this library before but the general idea is that you can send this same receipt every time and apple will return you the latest receipt info. You can use the latest receipt info to update/cancel the user subscription.

This is the documentation from apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Comment: so basically i can't do anything right now until the user opens the app? as receipt was never saved on server

Comment: This is the only way I was able to do it. I'm not sure if there is another workaround.